# QML scope a la angular using JSON

Tags: json, qml

How to load JSON in a model and how to have that model available globally ?

More detail: I have a JSON string I parse with JSON.parse. This produce a Javascript object. I'd like use that object as a model for my views the same way I do with Angular. So basically have a global model (scope) which I would use to build my UI.

My problem is that I am able to fit a JSON array ([...]) into a ListView (using append) but it does not seem to work with an object ({...}). Additionally, I don't see how to set a model that would be accessible by my whole qml page.

Really a newb here, so I my might be missing some fundamental QML concept. Any analogies to angular could help.